# What power settings can I use for Asus U32U-ES21 to achieve something close to the stated 10 hours battery life?

Tags: 12.04, power-management, asus

So when I got my [Asus X32U Notebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00713DPM4), the first thing I did was delete windows and install 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 - which works great, however I only get around 2.5 hours on battery - nothing close to the advertised 10 hours.

What settings or configurations can I use/adjust to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the BIOS settings online, and really there is not much you can do.  Also I do not have Ubuntu running on a laptop handy at this time, but I can tell you from experience what you can do. (these are personal suggestions).

Optimizing battery life helps you get the most out of battery operation, prolonging the charge/recharge cycle and improving recharging efficiency. You are advised to follow the suggestions set out below:

1. Dim your screen
2. Cut down on programs running in the background
3. Cut down external devices
4. Turn power off to Serial device
5. Hibernate not standby

**Source:** ["Laptop battery optimization and maintenance" on Cnet.com](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330043-263.html)

Use PowerTop.

> PowerTOP is a Linux tool to diagnose issues with power consumption and
>   power management. In addition to being a diagnostic tool, PowerTOP
>   also has an interactive mode where the user can experiment various
>   power management settings for cases where the Linux distribution has
>   not enabled these settings.<sup>**1**</sup>

Learn more about PowerTOP and download the latest version, <sup>**1**</sup>[click here](https://01.org/powertop).

Comment: Thanks thats certainly helped point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks

and also:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/IdentifyingIssues