# Extremely short battery life

Tags: power-management, lenovo

In Windows, my battery lasts several hours. In Ubuntu 12.04, it's dead before an hour and a half.

I've installed http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html but it has not solved the problem.

My power consumption looks like:
[image: powertop]

The computer is a lenovo U400 with an ATI Radeon GPU.

Comment: Have a look at this:[Laptop battery optimization and maintenance](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147094/what-power-settings-can-i-use-for-asus-u32u-es21-to-achieve-something-close-to-t/147144#147144)

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Jupiter** which is a light weight power and hardware control applet. It says improves battery life and works to some extent for me.

To install jupiter do this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Hope this helps.